# The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2005

I am writing a stored procedure for retrieving the xml structure for a menu control. This seems to be a valid code( according to me & it is wrong) but does not run well on query tester. How could i correct it of the error below is the code

```
;WITH Hierarchy AS
(
    SELECT
        MenUid,MenuName,ApplicationId,ParentMenuId, 1 AS 'Level'
    FROM
        dbo.Menu
    WHERE
        ParentMenuId = '-1'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        M.MenUid,M.MenuName,M.ApplicationId,M.ParentMenuId, Level + 1 AS 'Level'
    FROM
        dbo.Menu M
    INNER JOIN
        Hierarchy h ON M.ParentMenuId = h.MenuId
)
SELECT *
FROM Hierarchy
ORDER BY [Level],[MenuName]
```

Where ParentMenuId and MenuId are related. Certain other doubts i got are below

1. Is this perfectly fine to use `CTE` for menu. What other types have you been successful
2. `DataSet` and `ChildRelations` are good too(or maybe i am wrong) for this purpose ?

Give me more ideas on how you have accomplished menu system in your projects.

#### Input

```
MenuId      MenuName      ApplicationId    ParentMenuId

 1          MenuName1           1              -1

 2          MenuName2           1               1

 3          MenuName3           1               -1

 4          MenuName4           1               2
```

#### Output

```
<Output>
    <Menu>
        <MenuId>1</MenuId>
        <MenuName>MenuName1</MenuName>
        <ApplicationId>1</ApplicationId>
        <ParentMenuId>-1</ParentMenuId>
        <SubMenu>
            <Menu>
                <MenuId>2</MenuId>
                <MenuName>MenuName2</MenuName>
                <ApplicationId>1</ApplicationId>
                <ParentMenuId>1</ParentMenuId>
                <SubMenu>
                    <MenuId>3</MenuId>
                    <MenuName>MenuName4</MenuName>
                    <ApplicationId>1</ApplicationId>
                    <ParentMenuId>3</ParentMenuId>
                </SubMenu>
            </Menu>
        </SubMenu>
    </Menu>
    <Menu>
        <MenuId>4</MenuId>
        <MenuName>MenuName3</MenuName>
        <ApplicationId>1</ApplicationId>
        <ParentMenuId>-1</ParentMenuId>
    </Menu>
</Output>
```

Don't mind  about the xml structure i is easy to get with `FOR XML PATH` i am not getting the query to run in the first place.

Comment: Could you provide test data and desired output?

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk please look at the input and output section

Comment: Removed .NET tags: can't see anything about .NET in this question.

Comment: @Richard :) well 2 questions i asked below were. DataSet, ChildRelations

Comment: Unless a different client makes the error go away, then the client would matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd wager that

```
INNER JOIN
    Hierarchy h ON M.ParentMenuId = h.ParentMenuId
```

should in fact be

```
INNER JOIN
    Hierarchy h ON M.ParentMenuId = h.MenuId
```

*edit*

Using this sample data:

```
declare @Menu table (
    MenuId int,
    MenuName nvarchar(20),
    ApplicationId int,
    ParentMenuId int
)

insert @Menu values
(1, 'Name1', 1, -1),
(2, 'Name2', 1,  1),
(3, 'Name3', 1, -1),
(4, 'Name4', 1,  2)
```

and your query, with the above modification, I get

```
MenUid      MenuName             ApplicationId ParentMenuId Level
----------- -------------------- ------------- ------------ -----------
1           Name1                1             -1           1
3           Name3                1             -1           1
2           Name2                1             1            2
4           Name4                1             2            3
```

which looks correct. To help you we need to see **all** your relevant code.

Comment: exactly. now the query runs except that i don't get desired result.Please check input, output section

Comment: thanks. I find it hard now to generate xml structure since for xml path are not allowed along with union

Comment: here is the thing i am trying to do http://richarddingwall.name/2008/08/30/more-nested-xml-with-sql-server-n-level-tree-recursion/

Comment: @Deeptechtons as it explains in that blogpost, you have to use a user-defined function in this situation

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to retrieve the data flat and do the construction work on your application layer?

**EDIT:**

In general I would not reccomend a caching approach but, if the menu generation code was expensive, and assuming the menus don't change much, this would be a good target for caching.

Comment: well it is possible on database, hence why shouldn't i. I will try both,profile both and finally decide.

Comment: I suspect that the application code will perform the operation more efficiently and, its easier to farm an application tier.

Comment: i will follow the question. But i can't mark yours as answer as Aakash had originally answered the question which i asked. I will have to do this in application Tier until i get things right on DB side. Thanks :)